# Iphone app that launches a website without url bar

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to make a simple app for iOS. After opening it, i want it to open up safari with a certain website and that the address bar wouldn't show.

I'm completely new to iOS apps and I couldn't find anything similar from google. Maybe somebody has done it and can share the code or point me to somewhere where I can find it?

Comment: Be aware that app that simple open a website are allowed in AppStore. Appstore review guidelines 2.12: `Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected`

Comment: Hopefully they will accept as it is for a webapp type of booking system.

Comment: @user2485439 they should do, but you need to include at least one feature that you couldn't do as well on the website. - i've had apps rejected myself, because they were just XML readers for my website.

Comment: @user2485439 I've had apps rejected for this as well. A quick and easy why I get around it is have the first view after the launch image a native one and you get some basic information such as name etc and just pass it to the website so it is pre-filled already. Quick and simple and makes it so it isn't just a website anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a `UIWebView`, which by default doesn't include any controls or an address bar.

Class documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is a small example of usage:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];  
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.ie"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

This will effectively give you a browser view inside your application, without invoking Safari itself.

You can embed this `UIWebView` in a `UINavigationController`, or use it anywhere else in your applications view hierarchy.

One final point, the UIWebView class has many delegate methods which you can implement, these methods will be called by the system when a given event happens (URL loads, has errors, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much, will vote as correct after 8 minutes pass :)

Comment: bit of a side question, appearantly I have an os called tiger on the mac that I was given. Can I really only use xcode 2 on that or is there a way to get the newer ones to work?